# Need to access data from WCF service and update the data using Jquery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wcf, twitter-bootstrap

In my application Server side I have a WCF-Service. Client side I am using Bootstrap.As per requirement now I have to get the data from that wcf service and display in Grid,it had the buttons add,edit and delete.By selecting the any table row I need to update it and send data back to Database.All the actions I have to do only by Jquery or javascript.
Can anyone please suggest me the way to approach this.

Comment: What kind of WCF service - REST or SOAP? If it's SOAP, you will have a lot of work cut out for you.

Comment: Hi,It's a REST WCF service.

Answer (score 0):

As a note, Bootstrap isn't really relevant for retrieving data from a server.

Since you're using jQuery, you can use `$.ajax()` for this. (see the [jQuery.ajax() reference](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for more details).

For example, to get data from the server, you might do something like this:

```
$.get("url/to/rest/resource")
  .done(function( data ) {
    // Do something with the data
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.error("Failed to get data from server.");
  });
```

To save data to the database, I'm guessing that your REST service accepts a POST or PUT request:

```
var dataToSave = { name: "Joe", age: 28 };
$.post("url/to/rest/resource", dataToSave)
  .fail(function() {
    console.error("Failed to save data.");
  });
```